# How to combine 4 bytes into float value in Javascripts

Tags: javascript

I can send 4 bytes data to my javascript,

```
var data = new Uint8Array(data);

console.log('Data received: [ (data[0]) +', ' + (data[1]) +', ' + (data[2]) + ', ' + (data[3]) +  ']');

console.log('Data received: [ d2h(data[0]) +', ' + d2h(data[1]) +', ' + d2h(data[2]) + ', ' + d2h(data[3]) +  ']');

var hexvalue = ((d2h(data[4]) << 24) | (d2h(data[3]) << 16) | (d2h(data[2]) << 8) | d2h(data[1]));

value = parseFloat(hexvalue);
console.log(value);
```

In my LOG, I see this

```
LOG: Data received: [77, 249, 144, 66]
LOG: Data received: [4d, f9, 90, 42]
LOG: 710541312
```

I expected to get 72.49..
What did I do wrong?

Comment: `parseFloat()` is for parsing a string representation of a floating-point value.  Also why does your log message show 6 values in the square brackets when you only have 4 in the code?

Comment: oh. the "ad" is a marker for an another Array. 0x4290f94d is 72.49. I thought d2h will convert decimal to hex in string format...  I just took out the parseFloat(), I get the same 710541312 result...

Comment: without the a2h, I will get  LOG: Data received: [50, 140, 147, 66]. The numbers are now in dec.

Comment: What is *data* before you start? NB: It is strange to see `var` there, when you already use it as argument.

Comment: The data came from a function: app.receivedData = function(data) {

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a parsing problem, and there's no need to perform any hex conversions. Hex (like decimal) is just a *representation*. The values in your `Uint8Array` are already numbers.

To force those bytes to be interpreted as a 32-bit floating-point value, you just have to use the same buffer as the basis of a `Float32Array` instance:

```
var data = new Uint8Array(data);
var f32 = new Float32Array(data.buffer);
var f32value = f32[0];
```

*edit* — more explicitly:

```
var data = new Uint8Array(4);
data[0] = 0x4d;
data[1] = 0xf9;
data[2] = 0x90;
data[3] = 0x42;
var f32 = new Float32Array(data.buffer);
var f32value = f32[0];
console.log(f32value); // 72.4869155883789
```

Comment: I tried to console.log(f32value) and got this error... LOG: [ERR] RangeError: ArrayBuffer length minus the byteOffset is not a multiple of the element size [hyper/063e2092-9377-44b0-b364-15116340f171/fa13c7fb-73a9-4a3f-8af6-04489f75eaf4/cordova.js: 314]

Comment: The code I posted works if the "data" buffer contains *only* the 4 bytes of the value (`4290f94d`). If you've got extra garbage in the `data` buffer then it won't work.

Comment: Yeah, I took out the first marker. var f32data = [data[4], data[3], data[2], data[1]];
            var f32 = new Float32Array(f32data.buffer);
   var f32value = f32[0]; Can I do this?

Comment: No, you can't. In that example, `f32data` is a plain array, and that's radically different from a typed array.

Comment: var f32data = new Uint8Array(4);
       f32data[0] = d2h(data[1]);
    f32data[1] = d2h(data[2]);
    f32data[2] = d2h(data[3]);
    f32data[3] = d2h(data[4]);
            var f32 = new Float32Array(f32data.buffer);
   var f32value = f32[0]; console.log('Data received: [' +
    data[0] +', ' + d2h(data[1]) +', ' + d2h(data[2]) + ', ' + d2h(data[3]) + ', ' + d2h(data[4]) + ']'); console.log(f32value); LOG: Data received: [173, 42, 9c, f2, 8b] LOG: 5.885453550164232e-44

Comment: NO NO NO. You do not need that `d2h()` thing almost certainly. Why don't you just use the code I posted

Comment: console.log('Data received: [' +
    (data[0]) +', ' + (data[4]) +', ' + (data[3]) + ', ' + (data[2]) + ', ' + (data[1]) + ']'); LOG: Data received: [173, 223, 18, 155, 66]

Comment: Why are there 5 bytes logged in your 4 byte value? This is an extremely simple problem; what's going on?

Comment: And again, the value of a number when printed is just a **representation** of the number. `0x4d` and `77` are **exactly the same value**.  There's absolutely no need to perform a hex conversion.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "decimal byte".

Comment: I made a mistake to reverse the array order. Your solution works!!!! Thanks a lot