# Converting Microchip “eb” floating-point format to IEEE 754

Tags: javascript, floating-point

How do I convert floating-point data from a Microchip PIC12F675 to IEEE 754 binary 32-bit floating-point?

For example, the device sends bits 0x8111999A to represent approximately 4.55, and the IEEE-754 representation is 0x4091999A.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done into the issue and any attempts you've made to solve this issue yourself. Please read [ask] for tips on how to ask questions that are less likely to be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: I am using 12F675 controller the value that sent via serial as 4.55 then hex value of it that read via bluetooth terminal as 0x8111999a so the format of floating point is different than floating point value when using javascript 4.55 hex value is 0x4091999a the question is how to change this value to  0x4091999a I think there is a trick to do shifting of byte0 & byte1 but I do not know how to do in javascript

Comment: so how to do this rotation using javascript  to get value as 0x4091999a can you help me?

Comment: I tried also pic 16F series it is same as 12F series the format of floating point is same

Answer (score 2):

[Microchip Application Note 00575](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00575.pdf) discusses some Microchip floating-point formats for the PIC16/17 families. I do not see a version saying it is for the PIC12. On page 3, it compares Microchip’s format with IEEE-754 and says “The difference between the formats consists of a rotation of the top nine bits of the representation…” The top nine bits of 0x8111999A are 100000010. Rotating those right one bit makes 010000001, and replacing those in the original produces 0x4091999A. You should seek confirmation this holds for the PIC12 family.

This code shows how to rotate the top nine bits one bit right:

```
var x = 0x8111999a;

//  Disassemble the fields in x.
var Bits0to22  = x       & 0x7fffff; // Use mask to take low 23 bits.
var Bit23      = x >> 23 & 1;        // Shift 23 bits and take 1.
var Bits24to31 = x >> 24 & 0xff;     // Shift 24 bits and take 8.

//  Reassemble fields in desired order.
var y = Bit23 << 31 | Bits24to31 << 23 | Bits0to22;

console.log(x.toString(16));
console.log(y.toString(16));
```

Output is:

```
8111999a
4091999a
```

Comment: there is another issue how to combine four bytes into one variable?

Comment: @hitronics: That is a separate question, and there are already answers on Stack Overflow, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530994/how-to-combine-4-bytes-into-float-value-in-javascripts).

Comment: `var data = new Uint8Array(4);
data[3] = 0x9a;
data[2] = 0x99;
data[1] = 0x11;
data[0] = 0x81;
var f32 = new Float32Array(data.buffer);
var f32value = f32[0];
console.log(f32value.toString(16));  //-0.0000000000000000004c88c08`

Comment: the result is wrong -0.0000000000000000004c88c08 why not get hex value as 0x8111999a when combine  4 bytes?

Comment: @hitronics: Assemble the bytes into an integer first, and in the correct order. Then convert them to IEEE-754 format. Then reinterpret them as floating-point, as shown in the answer to the question I linked to. That said, Stack Overflow is not a personal code-writing service. It is incumbent upon you to learn and understand the concepts involved so you can write your own code. You can ask specific questions after searching for previous answers on Stack Overflow, but you should not keep asking new questions in comments.

Comment: all your efforts are appreciated thanks :)